# Would an iPhone delete text messages by itself?

Tags: iphone, sms

Would an iPhone 3G delete text messages by itself? I have lost some text messages and don't know where to find them! Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a direct answer for this, but if you have a jailbroken iPhone, you can attempt to recover deleted text messages using "Undelete SMS" - see [this blog post about it](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/07/30/undelete-sms-recovery/) and [a description by its author](http://www.zdziarski.com/blog/?p=1236).

Comment: My phone deleted my messages, but only me and my staff's message history. I thought it was an accident, maybe I accidentally deleted the history, buy the weird thing was that there was some texts written in the text box (right before you click send) that was actually in ukrainian or czech, with some emojis.. That'd take a bit work to write.. Some weeks ago, my mother in law went to my house at 1am, she said I called her twice but when she picked up the phone, i didn't say anything. She was sooo worried that she drove to my house, made sure everything's fine. It said in her phone that I called

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to see the SMS in spotlight? Worst case would be that the phone was unlocked while in your pocket and somehow (through the miracle of entropy) messages got deleted.

Otherwise the phone might be running out of space as to my knowledge there is a limit to 250,000 messages that can be stored on the phone (regardless of which GB model you have), what would supersede that message limit is if you have very little space left on your phone. By default the iPhone OS will make sure that it has space for temporary data and caches over SMS messages.

Comment: [citation needed]